# Playorm ScannerForClass exception in @NoSqlId at Amazon AWS Elastic Map Reduce

Tags: playorm

My jar in localhost or at AWS EC2 instance works like a charm, but just on Elastic MapReduce it fails with a "Never seen" Exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class=class com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle has two fields that have @NoSqlId annotation. One of them may be in a superclass`

I have tried to remove the ***(usegenerator = true)*** from ***@NoSqlId***, but didn't work.

**Exception:**

```
2012-12-11 12:00:14,454 INFO com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger (main): [rawlogger] starting NoSQL Service Provider and connecting
2012-12-11 12:00:14,637 INFO com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager (main): Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=MyConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
2012-12-11 12:00:15,261 INFO com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper (main): On keyspace=dmpExisting column families=[stringindice, dbocolumnmeta, dbodatabasemeta, dbotablemeta]
NOTE: WE WILL CREATE new column families automatically as you save entites that have no column family
2012-12-11 12:00:15,262 INFO com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl (main): Begin scanning for jars with nosql.Persistence.class
2012-12-11 12:00:15,289 INFO com.impetus.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer (main): adding folder to scan=file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-unjar5809470263616901335/
2012-12-11 12:00:15,289 INFO com.impetus.annovention.ClasspathDiscoverer (main): adding jar file for scanning=jar:file:/home/hadoop/project_w.jar!/
2012-12-11 12:00:16,212 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.UserURL
2012-12-11 12:00:16,260 INFO com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta (main): [proxies loaded in this one]classloaders that proxies class exists in=classloader list={java.net.URLClassLoader@158f9d3,sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cde100,sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@16f0472,}
2012-12-11 12:00:16,260 INFO com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta (main): [context classloader]classloaders that proxies class exists in=classloader list={java.net.URLClassLoader@158f9d3,sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cde100,sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@16f0472,}
2012-12-11 12:00:16,260 INFO com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta (main): [system classloader]classloaders that proxies class exists in=classloader list={sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cde100,sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@16f0472,}
2012-12-11 12:00:16,260 INFO com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta (main): [play jar in this classloader]classloaders that proxies class exists in=classloader list={java.net.URLClassLoader@158f9d3,sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cde100,sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@16f0472,}
2012-12-11 12:00:16,260 INFO com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta (main): [javassist jar in this classloader]classloaders that proxies class exists in=classloader list={java.net.URLClassLoader@158f9d3,sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cde100,sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@16f0472,}
2012-12-11 12:00:16,453 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.Request
2012-12-11 12:00:16,473 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.User
2012-12-11 12:00:17,167 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta
2012-12-11 12:00:17,246 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboDatabaseMeta
2012-12-11 12:00:17,248 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta
2012-12-11 12:00:17,313 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.alvazan.play.logging.LogEvent
2012-12-11 12:00:17,318 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.alvazan.play.logging.ServersThatLog
2012-12-11 12:00:28,399 INFO com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass (main): scanning class=class com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.UserURL

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning class(see chained exception)=class com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.UserURL
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:44)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34)
at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197)
at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:80)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:131)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:24)
at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:39)
at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.service.DataAccessService.<init>(DataAccessService.java:28)
at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.service.DataAccessService.getInstance(DataAccessService.java:22)
at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.main.DmpProcessorRunner.main(DmpProcessorRunner.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning field=private java.lang.String com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.UserURL.id for class=UserURL
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:196)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanFields(ScannerForClass.java:189)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanSingle(ScannerForClass.java:112)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:69)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class=class com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle has two fields that have @NoSqlId annotation.  One of them may be in a superclass
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.processIdFieldWorks(ScannerForClass.java:233)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectFieldImpl(ScannerForClass.java:207)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:194)
... 36 more
```

**My User class:**

```
@NoSqlEntity
public class User {
    @NoSqlId
    @NoSqlIndexed
    @Field
    private String id;

    @NoSqlIndexed
    @Field
    private String nome;

    @NoSqlManyToMany
    @Field
    private List<UserURL> urls = new ArrayList<UserURL>();

    @NoSqlManyToMany
    @Field
    private List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

**My UserURL class:**

```
@NoSqlEntity
public class UserURL {
    @NoSqlId(usegenerator = true)
    @Field
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String url'

    @NoSqlManyToOne
    @NoSqlIndexed
    private User user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have seen this issue ourselves recently and put a temporary fix in.  Grab the latest from master branch and try that and let me know.  The new code looks like this so it should tell us the two fields (or not scan that field twice).

```
    if(metaClass.getIdField() != null) {
        Field existingField = metaClass.getIdField().getField();
        if(field.equals(existingField))
            return true; // we already processed it
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("class="+metaClass.getClass()+" has two fields that have @NoSqlId annotation.  One of them may be in a superclass.  The two fields are="+field+" and="+existingField);
    }
```

NOTE: We are also looking for a better fix as sometimes this is caused by a double scan of a class file so we probably have another fix coming by the end of this week....we are currently talking about it via email right now.

Also, this issue is caused by scanning a class twice....is any of your code calling rescan method in NoSqlEntityManagerFactory?  (I am thinking not).  The latest should solve your issue for now and check back next week too.

Dean

Comment: Dean, thank you very much my friend! This fix works perfectly! I'll be watching for more updates.

My code is not calling rescan method.

Comment: no problem, anytime.  We have added a bit to the command line tool as well so feel free to use that to query into some of your data.  We use it ourselves and find we keep needing to add more and more to it.